# Elastic Search Highlighting Issue

Tags: elasticsearch

We are evaluating both Solr and Elasticsearch for a usecase. In Solr one of the parameters used in highlighting is hl.preserveMulti to preserve order of values in a multiValued data. Doing so in Solr, then it returns all of the values of the multivalued data in their original order. If this parameter is used, the values that have a hit are highlighted and the ones that do not contain a hit are returned un-highlighted.

In elasticsearch, with highlighting on, only the values which contains the highlighted snippet is returned back in _highlight and I am unable to get back rest of the values (which do not contain highlighting) from a multivalued list in _highlight

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

With Elasticsearch 2.2, you can play on the highlight query settings to return one fragment with the size of the field. It will return all the field value with highlighted value in it.

The query may look like this one:

```
curl -XPOST 'es_address/index1/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "fields": [],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field1": "foo"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "field1": {
        "fragment_size": 10000, // Insert your own value here
        "number_of_fragments": 1
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I did not test with other versions of Elasticsearch.

Comment: The above solution does not give me response like :  { _highlight : {"field1":["<em>foo</em> bar","choco bar"]}}.

Comment: Try with  `number_of_fragments: 0`. For `fragment_size`, just set it with the desired value